# Inserting node to linked list only goes to beginning or end

Tags: c++, list, insert

I've confused myself with this code. I want to insert the node with name "Joshua" into my linked list after the node with "James". However, I have it wrong and it only adds it to the beginning or end of the list based on the integer value in "insert("Joshua", 2);"

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    string name;
    Node *link;
};
typedef Node* NodePtr;

NodePtr listPtr, tempPtr;

void insert(string name, int n)
{

    NodePtr temp1 = new Node();
    temp1->name = name;
    temp1->link = NULL;
    if(n == 1){
        temp1->link = listPtr;
        listPtr = temp1;
        return;
    }
    NodePtr temp2 = listPtr;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        temp2 = temp2->link;
    }
    temp1->link = temp2->link;
    temp2->link = temp1;
}

void print()
{
    NodePtr temp = listPtr;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->name << endl;
        temp = temp->link;
    }
}

/*
 *
 */

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    listPtr = new Node;
    listPtr->name = "Emily";

    tempPtr = new Node;
    tempPtr->name = "James";
    listPtr->link = tempPtr;

    tempPtr->link = new Node;
    tempPtr = tempPtr->link;
    tempPtr->name = "Joules";
    tempPtr->link = NULL;

    print();
    insert("Joshua", 2);
    cout << endl;
    print();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    temp2 = temp2->link;
}
```

if `n=2` and you have `3` elements in the linked list, at the end of the above loop, you will be at the last node.Then the below will add the new node at the end.

```
temp1->link = temp2->link;
temp2->link = temp1;
```

You want to run the loop `1` less time.